# MySQL - How to select the value associated with the most recent date + the maximum/minimum of all the values

Tags: mysql

My table structure looks something like this:
1. Auto-generated primary key (integer)
2. name (non-unique)
3. value
4. date

I want to do a query that returns the value associated with the most recent date and also the maximum/minimum of the value for all dates, given a specific name.

For example, if I have a table like

```
--------------------------------
| 1 |  jack  | 2  | 2019-03-25 |
| 2 |  james | 3  | 2019-03-25 |
| 3 |  jack  | 3  | 2019-03-26 |
| 4 |  jack  | 3  | 2019-03-27 |
| 5 |  james | 10 | 2019-03-27 |
| 6 |  jack  | 5  | 2019-03-28 |
--------------------------------
```

then when I query it using the name 'jack', I want the result to look like

```
------------------------------
| name | current | max | min |
------------------------------
| jack |    5    |  5  |  2  |
------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: We like to see that you've tried something

Comment: You are looking for [Aggregate (GROUP BY) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: I know I can do MAX(value) and MIN(value) with GROUP BY name, but I can't figure out how to add the most recent value to the result.

Comment: So, show us the bits you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't tried anything and you don't know where to start, here's an approach

```
SELECT 
    name, -- first column is the name
    value as current, -- get the value as "current"
    (
        -- here we have nested query
        SELECT
            value
        FROM
            Test AS minT -- create an alias for the table to be able to refer it in the WHERE clause
        WHERE
            minT.name = name -- filters values only for the "name" that matches the name in the main query
        ORDER BY
            value ASC -- orders them by "value ASC" since we want the smallest value
        LIMIT 1 -- get only the first result
    ) as min,
    (
        SELECT
            value
        FROM
            Test as maxT
        WHERE
            maxT.name = name
        ORDER BY
            value DESC -- same as above just in reverse order
        LIMIT 1
    ) as max
FROM
    Test
ORDER BY -- orders the results by
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) ASC -- the diff (subtracts in days) the current date and the one in the table
LIMIT
    1 -- and just return the first row
```